# Can you center a Button in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to center a button in relative layout, is this possible? I've tried the Gravity and Orientation functions but they don't do anything.

Comment: Language? Framework? OS?

Comment: What language / framework / etc are you using?

Comment: @Arnold Spence: you beat me by 24 seconds :)

Comment: I'm guessing Android but I'll wait before setting the tags I guess.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using Stack Overflow. Yes I'm developing for Android. =)

Comment: No prob. The right tags will get the attention of the right poeple faster. Fixed :)

Comment: Please choose an answer for this.

Comment: +1 to Arnold Spence for being considerate. Some people on SO would have verbally destroyed the OP for just being "new".

Answer (score 412):

Try

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Exactly like this, it works for me:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#ff0000">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_mybutton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="124dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I doesn't work if you have match_parent for your width.

Comment: If you have match_parent for your width, it's already centred horizontally.

Answer (score 116):

You can use CENTER_IN_PARENT for relative layout.

Add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to element which you want to center in the RelativeLayout

Comment: That centers horizontally and veritcally, how 'bout layout_centerHorizontal=true

Answer (score 38):

Arcadia, just try the code below. There are several ways to get the result you're looking for, this is one of the easier ways.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/the_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Centered Button"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Setting the gravity of the RelativeLayout itself will affect all of the objects placed inside of it. In this case, it's just the button. You can use any of the gravity settings here, of course (e.g. center_horizontal, top, right, and so on).

You could also use this code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/the_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Centered Button"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. However, if I had multiple buttons and only wanted one centered how would I do that? The first code would center everything within the parent relativelayout. Also, how could I center the button at the top of it's row?

Comment: Just use the second example, and only add centerInParent to the button that you want centered. You can also use centerHorizontal, and layout_alignParentTop to align it to the top and center it horizontally. What exactly are you trying to achieve, I might can give a better example.

Comment: I'm barely beginning my studies of android development and trying to fully understand how to manipulate things to do what I want. Basically I want to stay away from aligning things with pixels because the picture could look very different on a different screen type/resolution. However, when you use the gravity command, everything follows it. I tried disabling gravity for a button by using ignoreGravity and it didnt work. This stuff is very tricky.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely can be. There are plenty of ways to do any particular layout. Best way is to sort of sketch it out in your head how you want it, and go from there. This quick tutorial may help some too: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html

Comment: Yeah I was actually doing that tutorial. I'm going through each of the tutorials and learning how to fully manipulate them, otherwise I won't have a grasp of how each one is different.

Answer (score 29):

**Summarized**

Adding:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

just works on RelativeLayout, if one of the following attributes is also set for the view:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

which alignes the child view to the parent view. The "center" is based on the axis of the alignement you have chosen:

**left/right -> vertical**

**top/bottom -> horizontal**

Setting the gravity of childs/content inside the view:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

is centering the child inside the parent view in any case, if there is no alignment set. Optional you can choose:

```
<!-- Axis to Center -->
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:gravity="center_vertical"

<!-- Alignment to set-->
android:gravity="top"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:gravity="left"
android:gravity="right"
android:gravity="fill"
...
```

Then there is:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

which is centering the view itself inside it's parent

And at last you can add the following attribute to the parents view:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Answer (score 10):

Its easy, don't align it to anything

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/the_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Centered Button"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the attribute `android:centerInParent="true"` inside a view ,
when you want to center the view in Relative layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NWE"
        android:textSize="30dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

To center align in one of the direction use android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" or android:layout_centerVertical="true" in the child layout

Answer (score 2):

It's really easy. Try the code below,

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/second_RL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/first_RL"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Code only answers are not welcomed here. Try to post more details as to why the above answer will work. :)

Comment: Thanks for the guideline. I'm new in here.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple, just use `Android:CenterInParent="true"` to center both in horizontal and vertical, or use `Android:Horizontal="true"` to center in horizontal and `Android:Vertical="true"`

And make sure you write all this in RelaytiveLayout

Answer (score 1):

Removing any alignment like  android:layout_alignParentStart="true" and
adding centerInParent worked for me. If the "align" stays in, the
centerInParent doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

you must have aligned it to left or right of parent view

don't use any of these when using    `android:centerInParent="true"` codes:-

`android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`

`android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`

`android:layout_alignRight=""`

etc.