# How to horizontally center composite list view items inside the list view?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view displaying items from a custom adapter which extends `ArrayAdapter`. Each item is a custom layout with a `RelativeLayout` being the root view. Now, I want this `RelativeLayout` to be centered horizontally inside the list view, but I everything I tried seems to fail.

Here's my custom adapter `getView` method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.screens_listview_row, parent, false);
    return row;
}
```

And here's the file `screens_listview_row.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/root"
   .....
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

At first, it seemed like my layout parameters in the `RelativeLayout` were completely ignored, and it really was the case because i used `inflate(R.layout.screens_listview_row, null)`, what is a problem like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1503477/797390) says.

So now the only thing ignored is the `layout_gravity` parameter. I also tried `layout_marginLeft` (Everything in this layout is in absolute sizes so I could center it myself by giving a left margin...) but Android ignored it too. What is the problem here?

Comment: there is no gravity in a relative_layout. You can, however, center each child using centerInParent, centerHorizontal, centerVertical.

Comment: There are not children, currently. The relative layout simply has a background image which is not centered, and it should be.

Comment: show how you set the background.

Comment: An attribute in the file: `android:background="@drawable/screens_listview_row_background"`

Comment: usually backgrounds are stretched across the item. Is it a 9-patch ?

Comment: Like I said, I use absolute positioning in this layout (The app is meant for a single screen size, and it has a quite complicated layout, so... This makes things easier.). There's a absolute width for the background, otherwise it would be stretched, yes.

Comment: i don't think the background rendering is modified by the layout params. a background for any view is supposed to stretch across all the view.

Comment: I checked the `Show layout bounds` option in the `Developer options` in my phone, and I clearly see that the `RelativeLayout` is as the size of the background, thus not taking all the horizontal space. There **has** to be a way to make it centered...

Comment: you'll probably have to put your content in another relativelayout, using the centerInParent attribute.

Comment: I guess I'll put that background inside an `ImageView`. But it's weird that there's no way to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find out how to control the position of the items inside the `ListView`, so instead I made the `ListView` width exactly as the items' width, then controlled its position (Which practically controls the items' position).

Comment: The problem with this is that on a tablet you cannot use your thumbs to scroll the content. This leaves with poor UX.

Answer (score 2):

try to use gravity instead of layout_gravity  (as i know gravity is for the content of layout)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/root"
   .....
   android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`, doesn't work either.

Comment: that's for linear layouts and a few others, and that's the other way around. gravity defines the position of the children, layout_gravity is set in a child to override that property.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed +1 .